# warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts] in C

Tags: c, gcc, base64, warnings

I have a base64 encoding and decoding implementation in C. I didn't make it, I just copied it.

When I compile it with this command ...

```
gcc -Wall -g -c main.c
```

... it's emitting these warnings:

```
source/base64.h: In function ‘base64_decode’:
source/base64.h:45:75: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
   45 |         uint32_t sextet_a = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
      |                                                                       ~~~~^~~~~
source/base64.h:46:75: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
   46 |         uint32_t sextet_b = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
      |                                                                       ~~~~^~~~~
source/base64.h:47:75: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
   47 |         uint32_t sextet_c = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
      |                                                                       ~~~~^~~~~
source/base64.h:48:75: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
   48 |         uint32_t sextet_d = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
      |
```

`main.c` can be as simple as

```
#include "base64.h"
```

This is the cut back version of `base64.h` that yields those warnings:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
static const char encoding_table[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                                'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                                'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                                'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                                'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                                'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                                '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'};
static char *decoding_table = NULL;
 
void build_decoding_table() {
 
    decoding_table = malloc(256);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        decoding_table[(unsigned char) encoding_table[i]] = i;
}
 
 
void base64_cleanup() {
    free(decoding_table);
}
 
 
char *base64_decode(const char *data,
                             size_t input_length) {
 
    if (decoding_table == NULL) build_decoding_table();
    if (input_length % 4 != 0) return NULL;
 
    size_t output_length = input_length / 4 * 3;
    if (data[input_length - 1] == '=') (output_length)--;
    if (data[input_length - 2] == '=') (output_length)--;
 
    char *decoded_data = malloc(output_length+1);
    if (decoded_data == NULL) return NULL;
 
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < input_length;) {
 
        uint32_t sextet_a = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
        uint32_t sextet_b = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
        uint32_t sextet_c = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
        uint32_t sextet_d = data[i] == '=' ? 0 & i++ : decoding_table[data[i++]];
 
        uint32_t triple = (sextet_a << 3 * 6)
        + (sextet_b << 2 * 6)
        + (sextet_c << 1 * 6)
        + (sextet_d << 0 * 6);
 
        if (j < output_length) decoded_data[j++] = (triple >> 2 * 8) & 0xFF;
        if (j < output_length) decoded_data[j++] = (triple >> 1 * 8) & 0xFF;
        if (j < output_length) decoded_data[j++] = (triple >> 0 * 8) & 0xFF;
    }
    decoded_data[output_length] = '\0';
 
    return decoded_data;
}
```

**How can I clear the warnings?**

Comment: *The code you're asking about* should be presented as a [mre] in the question itself.  Evidently that would be part of your `base64.h`, in the vicinity of lines 123-126.

Comment: The warning is there because `char` is a signed type on some machines. It's not actually an issue in the program for valid inputs. Note that this library doesn't handle invalid inputs sanely*, which is quite insane considering base64 strings are usually from external sources!!! (* The issue found by the warning, plus the use of uninitlaized values in `decoding_table`. And, of course, the complete lack of error reporting.)

Comment: @ikegami thanks, and what should i change to stop showing that warning?

Comment: The warning is for using a `char` as an index, for the reason I already gave. So don't use a `char` as a index.

Comment: @LimeStone, the point of my previous comment was not that you should shrink the external file to which you have linked.  It was that the relevant contents of that file should be reduced to an MRE and ***edited into the question itself*** to make the question self-contained.

Comment: @ikegami bro thanks a lot, i converted that data[i++] to int like (int)data[i++] and it didn't show the warning anymore. Thank you!

Comment: @Lime Stone, why allocation 256 for `decoding_table` yet only populate 64?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica idk, i got it from a web source. thanks for pointing it tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the GCC warnings enabled by its `-Wall` option is `-Wchar-subscripts`, which causes GCC to warn about uses of values (specifically) of type `char` as array subscripts.  [The GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) explains it this way:

> Warn if an array subscript has type `char`. This is a common cause of error, as programmers often forget that this type is signed on some machines.

In fact, it seems to be more common for `char` to be a signed type than not.

Your `base64_decode()` function runs afoul of that check with several uses of `data[i++]` as an array subscript.  If you can be sure that the input (stored in `data`) consists *only* of valid base64 then that's probably moot, because C requires all of the digits used in every base-64 variant I know to be represented with positive values.  In that case, you could suppress these warnings without modifying the code by adding `-Wno-char-subscripts` to your `gcc` command line.  However, that will suppress those generally reasonable warnings for the rest of your program too, so it's a bit heavy handed.

If you're open to modifying the decoder then a softer touch would involve adding conversions of those appearances of `data[i++]` to a different integer type.  `unsigned char` would be the best choice for that.

On the other hand, the best solution overall would probably be to choose a better Base64 implementation.  The `char` subscripts are only one of several things to dislike about the one you are looking at.

Comment: okay, thanks for taking time to write this.

Answer (score 1):

@ikegami spared his time and saved me, the warning doesn't show anymore when converting data[i++] to int like `(int)data[i++]`.

Comment: Yet that doesn't actually address the issue the warnings were trying to bring to your attention.  If your data contain negative values then they are still negative after converting to `int`.  If you want to resolve the warnings by converting the data then the best type to convert to would be `unsigned char`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks a lot. the same is if I convert to unsigned int instead of unsigned char?

Comment: If you convert to `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned char` then negative inputs will be converted to numbers much larger than the largest valid index into the array set up in `*decoding_table`.  Converting to `unsigned char` is the best way to make it work the same whether `char` is signed or unsigned.